# Does "System restart required" affect code on server?

Tags: server, mysql

On my ubuntu vps 16.04 server I have two websites running. However earlier today, when a user was using one of the websites it did not update the mysql database as it should have. When I logged into the server to see if there was any errors there was nothing wrong. The only thing there was;

`System restart required` after I done this I downloaded the db to my local machine where I manually updated it there and then re-uploaded to the server. This then worked fine. This has happened once before, but I couldn't find an error. So am concerned as I do not want this to happen again. Is there a way I can automate the system restart if the message is displayed? As I have another ubuntu vps 16.04 server from linode and never seem to have this problem.

It's like it isn't caching properly. Not entirely sure if it is my code or the server. As the code runs fine locally.

Comment: Look at `/var/log/apt/term.log` and see if an upgrade did happen!

Comment: Look to see if an update was done on your server or mysql that might be the source of the `system restart required` info seen. Check with your provider or check your update logs

Comment: I run the first command, you mentioned, but to be honest I don't understand most of it

Comment: sorry it's where your apt-get log is kept check to see what happened to your server if an update occurred, use `cat /var/log/apt/term.log | grep "Log started"` now look for recent dates

Comment: What you saw was probably not related to the restart required-message. Because mysql relies mostly on userland libraries, and can be restarted by apt when upgrading. Why it happend? I have no idea, and you have to look into your applications log, and mysql's log.